# Little extension of the Leibniz rule

Tags: calculus, integration

$ \int_A^B F(A, x)dx $

Let's say I have an integral on this form.  If F didn't depend on A (let's say it depends on C instead), the derivative of this integral with respect to A would simply be -F(C,A).  However, since A is not only the boundary, but an argument on F, how can I take the derivative of this integral with respect to A?

Answer (score 0):

Define $$f(s,t)=\int_s^BF(t,x)\,dx.$$Say your integral is $I(A)$. Then $$I(A)=f(A,A),$$so the several-variable chain rule shows that $$I'(A)=\frac{\partial f}{\partial s}(A,A)+\frac{\partial f}{\partial t}(A,A).$$The first term is given by the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus, while the standard Leibniz rule gives the second term.